# My homescreen app (which starts on boot) needs to list and link to inbuilt apps like camera, clock etc. How can do that?

Tags: android

I have an activity that starts at boot with 9 icons in it. When user clicks on these icons, the respective apps need to be launched. Some of them are inbuilt like camera, clock, internet etc. This is on Android 3.0 (tablet). How should i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

1. First get list all of the available apps:

   ```
    final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
   ```

   > ```
   >    //get a list of installed apps.
   >             List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm
   >                     .getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
   >
   >             for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
   >
   >                 Log.d(TAG, "Installed package :" + packageInfo.packageName);
   >                 Log.d(TAG,
   >                         "Launch Activity :"
   >                                 + pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageInfo.packageName)); 
   >
   >             }// the getLaunchIntentForPackage returns an intent that you can use with startActivity() 
   >         }
   > ```
2. Link every app to a drawable(icon) and the intent
3. Start that intent when the icon is clicked.

Comment: Hmnn...this is also an interesting approach and maybe i should do it this way. Thanks for the info

Comment: hi, when i tried to startActivity(pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageInfo.packageName));, it is not starting the intent. I am checking with a if loop for the correct packageInfo.packageName and then inside the startActivity is not happening. Anything else i should do here?

Comment: PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();Intent monIntent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.vdb.n");
    startActivity(monIntent);

Answer (score 0):

I think the launching of inbuilts does not depend on Android version.
[Launching camera](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-quick-tip-launching-the-camera/)
[Launching browser](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/launch-android-browser/)
There are a lot of tips online. Search deeper.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response. Problem Solved!

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [adw-launcher-android](http://code.google.com/p/adw-launcher-android/)  ?

This project is open-source and it contains classes which lists the in-built/installed applications and opens them inside this application itself.

Answer (score -1):

I think this might help

```
final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
startActivity(mainIntent);
```

From this List you can take the required apps